# HTML - Tags are marked red

Tags: html

```
<**center**>
 <h2>
  <**font** size = "+3" style="color: blueviolet; font-family: Geneva;">Game Features<**/font**>
 </h2>
<**/center**>
```

I don't understand why  and  tags are marked red in my code but it still works well?
I've tried to see if there are any errors but there seem to be none.
I'm new to HTML so hope you guys help me with this ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IDE is likely trying to inform you that the [`<center>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) and [`<font>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font) tags are both deprecated and should generally be avoided in new markup.

Per the note on the linked MDN pages:

> This feature is no longer recommended. Though some browsers might still support it, it may have already been removed from the relevant web standards, may be in the process of being dropped, or may only be kept for compatibility purposes. Avoid using it, and update existing code if possible […]